# Namespace / Class Qualifier

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I have a solution with several projects.  One of them is Contexts (where the default namespace is XYZ), and another is BackOffice (where the default namespace is XYZ.BackOffice).  BackOffice has a reference to Contexts.

I created a new class (Foo) in Contexts and I specified that Foo's namespace is XYZ.  I then wrote some code in BackOffice that used Foo.  I DID NOT QUALIFY Foo when I used it, nor did I add a using directive, and the build failed, as I expected.  I then changed all Foo to XYZ.Foo and did another build.  This time it was successful.  I then removed the XYZ's that I had just added, and the build is STILL successful.

How is it now "remembering" the namespace?  I did a clean and rebuild; no change.  I dropped Foo from Contexts and re-add it; VS2008's automatic error checking showed the errors I expected, but then the next build was still successful.

This only bothers me because I fear that, although I get a successful build, when my teammates check out my code, they may not.

Answer (score 0):

You must have a namespace qualifier somewhere. It may have a using somewhere that didn't get removed. Close your project and reopen. Sometimes there is a cached version of VS projects that probably is not getting updated in your case. Not sure what else to look for.

Comment: I would think so, but I searched "using.*XYZ\;" through the whole solution; there is no using that didn't get removed.  It is apparently being remembered "somewhere", but closing and re-opening the solution didn't change it.

Comment: also, you can add namespaces in web.config as under section <pages> 
      <namespaces>. Are you sure none of your team members have done this?